# How do I invoke an AWS Amplify function from my app?

Tags: react-native, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I've followed the AWS Amplify documentation and created a new function with the `amplify` CLI, and have tested it both in the console and locally (using `mock`), but I see nothing about how to invoke the function from my React Native app.

How do I invoke an AWS Amplify function from my app?

Comment: You presumably created a REST or GraphQL API. If GraphQL see [set up your app code](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/overview/#setup-your-app-code). If REST, see [fetching data](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/fetch/q/platform/js/).

Comment: @jarmod Ah so there's just an additional step involved: `amplify add api`, and hook that up the the function?

Comment: Basically, yes. That will create an API Gateway API for REST or a GraphQL endpoint for GraphQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options, here are a few listed below:

Option 1) Create an api gateway that calls your lambda function via proxy.  This is very easy to set up and there are plenty of tutorials.  After that step is completed, just call it like any other api. See this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html

Option 2) amplify add api and choose graphql.  This will set up a graphql Appsync api.  From there you can add a call to your function in your schema.graphql file and call it using either the code generated api or by just using a plain graphql client. See this article to set it up in your schema: https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/api-graphql/lambda-resolvers/q/platform/js/

Option 3) You may also be able to just use Lambda function URLS.  I have not used them yet but I think this should also work like the api gateway.  Here is the article that shows you how to set this up: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-urls.html

All of the above options are pretty easy to get going.  If you plan to use Appsync graphql for your app, I would go with option 2.  Otherwise I would probably stick with 1 or 3.